# Pass "this" from a click event to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is not working. I would like to pass "this" (which would be .dot) from the click event to the function, `findTargetSlideOfDot` but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. thanks

```
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function() {
    var targetSlide = findTargetSlideOfDot;
    changeSlide(targetSlide);
})

function findTargetSlideOfDot() {
    // find the slide number the user wants to see
    var get = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
        return v.indexOf('slide_') === 0;
    }).join();
    var targetSlide = '.' + get;

    return targetSlide;
}

function changeSlide(targetSlide) {
    // hide current slide and dot
    $('.slide.active, .dot.active').removeClass('active');
    $(targetSlide).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass it as a parameter an actually *call* that function. And the improvement shown by Colton should be applied as well:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function(e) {
    var targetSlide = findTargetSlideOfDot( e.target );
    changeSlide(targetSlide);
})

function findTargetSlideOfDot( element ) {
    // find the slide number the user wants to see
    var get = $.grep(element.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
        return v.indexOf('slide_') === 0;
    }).join();
    var targetSlide = '.' + get;

    return targetSlide;
}

function changeSlide(targetSlide) {
    // hide current slide and dot
    $('.slide.active, .dot.active').removeClass('active');
    $(targetSlide).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: shouldnt it be $(this) ?

Comment: No, he is using `className.split` on the parameter, which is a native DOM property

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function() {
    var targetSlide = $(this);
    changeSlide(targetSlide);
})

function changeSlide(targetSlide) {
    // hide current slide and dot
    //$('.slide.active, .dot.active').removeClass('active');
    $(targetSlide).toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
.dot{
width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px; margin: 5px;
}
.dot.active{
background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dot">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, modify your click function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function(e) {
    // e.target should refer to the element with the dot class
})
```

Here's a functional code pen too: http://codepen.io/csavage1994/pen/Mppxaa

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function(e) {
   findTargetSlideOfDot(e.target);
});
```

which gives you the element that triggered the event (was clicked)

and:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dot', function(e) {
   findTargetSlideOfDot(e.currentTarget);
});
```

which gives you the element that had the event listener registered.